# Fail to run Remote GPIO code from a PC using python3

Tags: gpio, python, remote, pigpio, gpiozero

I'm trying to run a remote GPIO code from a Linux machine to operate on RPI3.

Code is running OK on another RPI3 to control each other, but when trying to do so from a PC, it fails.

I followed the [gpiozero doc](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html), and install as described, with no success.

As an example, I try to run this simple code on RPI3 with an IP address `192.168.2.113`:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from signal import pause

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.2.113')

button = Button(2)
led = LED(17, pin_factory=factory)

led.source = button.values

pause()
```

and I get this error:

```
/home/guy/venv/untitled/bin/python /home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/gpio_from_desktop.py
/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:452: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named 'RPi'
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:452: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named 'RPIO'
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:452: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: No module named 'pigpio'
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:452: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from native: unable to open /dev/gpiomem or /dev/mem; upgrade your kernel or run as root
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guy/Documents/github/Rpi/GPIO_Projects/gpio_from_desktop.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpiozero import LED, Button
  File "/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .devices import (
  File "/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 486, in <module>
    Device.pin_factory = _default_pin_factory()
  File "/home/guy/venv/untitled/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 453, in _default_pin_factory
    raise BadPinFactory('Unable to load any default pin factory!')
gpiozero.exc.BadPinFactory: Unable to load any default pin factory!

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Did you pip install pigpio on the WIndows box?  Did you set the needed environment variables?

Comment: @joan- a) pigpio: installed using pip. b) it is a linux machine c)enviroment vars- no. how ?

Comment: `No module named 'RPi'` .... you do not have the correct modules installed

Comment: @jsotola - after installation on RPI.GPIO and RPIO - still same error

Comment: @joan - can you please exaplain how to use those enviroment variables?

Comment: @joan - please your answer

Comment: [Environment Variables](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html#environment-variables)

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have installed the modules on your Linux box, but not set the Environment variables.

From [4. Configuring Remote GPIO](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)

> #### [4.3. Environment variables](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)
>
> The simplest way to use devices with remote pins is to set the
>   `PIGPIO_ADDR` environment variable to the IP address of the desired
>   Raspberry Pi. You must run your Python script or launch your
>   development environment with the environment variable set using the
>   command line. For example, one of the following:
>
> ```
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 python3 hello.py
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 python3
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 ipython3
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 idle3 &
> ```
>
> If you are running this from a PC (not a Raspberry Pi) with gpiozero
>   and the pigpio Python library installed, this will work with no
>   further configuration. However, if you are running this from a
>   Raspberry Pi, you will also need to ensure the default pin factory is
>   set to `PiGPIOFactory`. If `RPi.GPIO` is installed, this will be selected
>   as the default pin factory, so either uninstall it, or use another
>   environment variable to set it to `PiGPIOFactory`:
>
> ```
> $ GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=pigpio PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 python3 hello.py
> ```
>
> This usage will set the pin factory to `PiGPIOFactory` with a default
>   host of `192.168.1.3`. The pin factory can be changed inline in the
>   code, as seen in the following sections.
>
> With this usage, you can write gpiozero code like you would on a
>   Raspberry Pi, with no modifications needed. For example:
>
> ```
> from gpiozero import LED
> from time import sleep
>
> red = LED(17)
>
> while True:
>     red.on()
>     sleep(1)
>     red.off()
>     sleep(1)
> ```
>
> When run with:
>
> ```
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3 python3 led.py
> ```
>
> will flash the LED connected to pin 17 of the Raspberry Pi with the IP
>   address `192.168.1.3`. And:
>
> ```
> $ PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.4 python3 led.py
> ```
>
> will flash the LED connected to pin 17 of the Raspberry Pi with the IP
>   address `192.168.1.4`, without any code changes, as long as the
>   Raspberry Pi has the pigpio daemon running.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows PC, it is slightly different.  We can't put environment variables into the command, so we need to first SET the environment variables, and the run as normal.

Do this once:
SET PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3
SET GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=pigpio
(type SET to see all the environment variables)

Now run the app:
python led.py

It is possible the SETting of the environment variables like this is not persistent, and may need to be done again after boot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/118702)